# How to Move Content Items Between Modules in 2sxc?

Tags: 2sxc

I have content items already entered on a page/module and displaying. I created a new page/module/app and have a few new content items displaying there. I am ready to make the new stuff live, but I need to get the existing Content Items from the old page/module moved over to the new page/module. This seems easy, but I am lost as to how to approach it.

Comment: I would love to help but your description could mean so many things. Could you provide more details, like are you also switching to another installation? is it going to another app, or are you just moving the module? or do you need to keep the old module and just duplicate the items list, etc.?

Comment: Using 2sxc Content app 3.01.01. Same site, different pages. Re-using the People content type. On page A we have 27 staff members showing. We added page B showing the "leadership" people. One of the 27 staff members needs to move from the Staff page to the Leadership page. I simply don't see the steps that would allow me to get this user moved over without entering them anew. It seems like there should be a simple way to add an empty slot for a 'People' and then select which staff person (maybe by name or EntityID) I want to go in that position. Since they are already in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome, thanks for the additional info. Basically you insert a new module, and then "replace" the demo-item shown with a real one. Here's a recipe for this :https://azing.org/2sxc/r/rgZWxnFB